# Convert CGPath points to a different UIView reference

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, cgpath

I'm facing a problem I'm not sure how to solve. I have a CGPath defined for a specific view, using that view's bounds. Another view needs to make use of that path but of course, the coordinates are not right (according to the second view's layer). So I was hoping to find something like:

`[view2 convertPoint:view1.center fromView:view1];`

but converting a CGPath instead of a point.

Is there any equivalent? Is that even possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no function for convenient transform CGPath between views coordinating system, but you can use `CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath` and apply affine transforms like `CGAffineTransformScale` and `CGAffineTransformTranslate`

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know that method `CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath` I've translated the whole CGPath taking the first view's `frame.origin` and converting that point to the second view coordinates system.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. This is what it looks like now in latest Swift version:
`var transform: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: otherView.frame.origin.x, y: otherView.frame.origin.y)` and then you call: 
`transformedPath = originalPath.copy(using: &transform)`